# Regarding Metrizability of a covering space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I am solving a problem from Hatcher's chapter 3 problem 3.3.15.

For an n-manifold M and a compact subspace $A\subset M$, show that $H_n(M,M-A;R)$ is isomorphic to the group $\Gamma_R(A)$ of sections of the covering space $M_R\rightarrow M$ over A, That is, maps $A\rightarrow M_R$ whose composition with $M_R\rightarrow M$ is the identity.

One way to do this can be to extend a certain section over A to a section over an open set containing A and then and then using excision to say $H_n(M|A)$=$H_n(U|A)$ and further showing the isomorphism between $\Gamma_R(A)$ and $\Gamma_R(U)$. Now the question that I have is if $M_R$ is metrizable then I can use certain Theorem given below,

(Theorem: Let E be any space and F be a metric space. Let K$\subset$E be compact, $f:E→F$ be continuous, locally injective near every point p$\in$K, and (globally) injective on K. Then f is also injective on some open neighbourhood N of K.)
to construct such an extension.
However, I don't know if $M_R$ is metrizable.

The other way is construct the extension on "pieces" or sheets covering $A$ and work backwords. Is it true that $M_R$ is metrizable assuming M is metrizable? Since M_R consists of disjoint copies of M and the two-sheeted orientable cover of M $\tilde{M}$ it might be true but I am not too sure.

Comment: More generally when is a covering space of a manifold which is metrizable a metrizable space?

Comment: Have you come across the necessary and sufficient conditions to be metrizable before?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need metrizable to do the problem. What I would do is first define a map from $H_n(M,M-A)$ to $\Gamma(A)$ essentially by inclusion. To see it is surjective we note that any section on $A$ can be extended to $M$ via partition of unity, then lemma 3.27(a) gives surjective. To see injective,use lemma 3.27(a) again by considering the zero section on $M$.

Comment: @Simplyorange Could you elaborate more on what you mean by partition of unity? I couldn't really follow that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually ignore my "partition of unity". Surjectivity should also follow from the proof of lemma 3.27(a). Notice that the proof works if you merely assume there is a continuous section on $A$, rather than the entire manifold $M$. For a reference see algebraic topology by Tom Dieck theorem 16.3.2.

Comment: Thanks I shall have a look at the same.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I should have but I don't remember them very well. I do know about the metrizability and paracompactness equivalence for manifolds but then it reduces to showing Mr is paracompact. Could you point me in to a reference or the condition you are talking about. Thanks.